# React onClick doest work correctly on if conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with React.

I wrote a function:

```
   function click(event) {
    let element = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".infos__content");
    if (element.style.display) {
        alert("test")
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        alert("test1")
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

and i called this function successfully in a DIV Container on the "onClick" attribute but it works for just one time, when i click on my div Container again, my if conditional always is true, does anyone know why?

I have google it already but cant find a solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use If statement inside your function to check the current style state of your element and then change accordingly.

```
function click(event) {
    let element = event.currentTarget.querySelector(".infos__content");
    if (element.style.display === "block") {
        alert("test")
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        alert("test1")
        element.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are first checking `element` it will be ''.  This will evaluate to false.

```
element.style.display
''
```

Then when you assign 'none', it will be 'none'.

```
element.style.display='none'
'none'

element.style.display
'none'
```

'none' is a true string value so the expression will always be true.  To make your evaluation false you must assign '' or `null`.